# eclipse and subversion issues

Tags: eclipse, svn

I set up an svn repository, and got it all working. However, whenever I delete a file in eclipse, svn complains about it: Running `svn st` gives the line:

```
!       filename
```

which seems to mean, as far as I can tell, that svn wants me to delete it with `svn rm filename`. However, I have no way to tell eclipse to do this. In addition, I couldn't commit until I had fixed this, which entailed creating the file again, then deleting it with `svn rm`.

Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you working with Subversion as an Eclipse plugin or from outside Eclipse? If you work with it as a plugin, the plugin should handle a lot of the file deletes/additions for you on commits.

Comment: @Thomas Owens From the command line, outside eclipse.

Comment: Is it an option to install something like Subclipse? Because that makes working with Eclipse + SVN much easier.

Comment: Aha, exactly what I'm looking for. Put that as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are working with Eclipse and Subversion, I recommend checking out some Eclipse plugins to make your life easier. I tend to use [Subclipse](http://subclipse.tigris.org/), but you can also use [Subversive](http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/). Having version control integrated into your development environment makes managing your workflow much easier, I think.